# Running a cron job from another shell

Tags: shell, cron

I would like `cron` to run a script from a specific shell (Zsh). I thought the following would work:

```
00 02 * * * exec zsh; /path/to/script.sh
```

but apparently it doesn't, why?

This also made me wonder, how do I find out what **shell** and **init scripts** does `cron` run first prior to running the entry in crontab?

Comment: Did you add #!/bin/zsh at the beginning?

Comment: Is `script.sh` a zsh script or do you want zsh to launch an `sh` script? What's the `exec` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks @Ghassan. I didn't have a working shebang, partly because of I was suffering from the same problem reported [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126812/path-independent-shebangs). I should be able to fix this now.

Comment: @Josh You're welcome dude. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
00 02 * * * exec /usr/bin/zsh /path/to/script.sh
```

That will tell zsh to run the script. Now you want it to be run in zsh doesn't matter what, just add the shebang in the start:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
the_rest
```

Comment: why is everybody using an 'exec' before the shell command in cron?  Simply using '/usr/bin/zsh /path/to/script.sh' is sufficient and exec is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Cron has several enviromental variables configured in `/etc/crontab`, specifically `SHELL` and `PATH`.  The default value for `SHELL` is `/bin/sh`.  So unless this is changed or otherwise specified in a script, `cron` will execute commands using `sh`.

Comment: NOTE:  Some versions of cron allow specification of some global variables.  To be sure checkout the man pages for cron, crond, and crontab for your particular distribution.