# Path independent shebangs

Tags: shell, zsh, cron, path

I have a script that I want to be able to run in two machines. These two machines get copies of the script from the same git repository. The script needs to run with the right interpreter (e.g. `zsh`).

Unfortunately, **both** `env` and `zsh` live in different locations in the local and remote machines:

#### Remote machine

```
$ which env
/bin/env

$ which zsh
/some/long/path/to/the/right/zsh
```

#### Local machine

```
$ which env
/usr/bin/env

$which zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

How can I set up the shebang so that running the script as `/path/to/script.sh` always uses the `Zsh` available in `PATH`?

Comment: Are you sure `env` isn't in both /bin and /usr/bin? Try `which -a env` to confirm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot solve this through shebang directly, since shebang is purely static.  What you could do is having some »least common multiplier« (from a shell perspective) in the shebang and re-execute your script with the right shell, if this LCM isn't zsh.  In other words: Have your script executed by a shell found on all systems, test for a `zsh`-only feature and if the test turns out false, have the script `exec` with `zsh`, where the test will succeed and you just continue.

One unique feature in `zsh`, for example, is the presence of the `$ZSH_VERSION` variable:

```
#!/bin/sh -

[ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && exec zsh - "$0" ${1+"$@"}

# zsh-specific stuff following here
echo "$ZSH_VERSION"
```

In this simple case, the script is first executed by `/bin/sh` (all post-80s Unix-like systems understand `#!` and have a `/bin/sh` , either Bourne or POSIX but our syntax is compatible to both).  If `$ZSH_VERSION` is *not* set, the script `exec`'s itself through `zsh`.  If `$ZSH_VERSION` is set (resp. the script already is run through `zsh`), the test is simply skipped.  Voilà.

This only fails if `zsh` isn't in the `$PATH` at all.

**Edit:** To make sure, you only `exec` a `zsh` in the usual places, you could use something like

```
for sh in /bin/zsh \
          /usr/bin/zsh \
          /usr/local/bin/zsh; do
    [ -x "$sh" ] && exec "$sh" - "$0" ${1+"$@"}
done
```

This could save you from accidentally `exec`'ing something in your `$PATH` which is not the `zsh` you're expecting.

Comment: I upvoted this for elegance but it does, in principle, have security/compatibility issues, if the first `zsh` in the `$PATH` is not the one you expect.

Comment: Tried to address it.  Question is, whether you can always be sure whether a `zsh` binary in the standard locations really is a `zsh`.

Comment: You can dynamically path the !bang line. You can also ask `zsh` itself where it is with `zsh -c 'whence zsh'`. More simply you can just `command -v zsh`. See my answer for how to dynamically path the `#!bang`.

Comment: Calling the `zsh` binary from `$PATH` to get the path of the `zsh` binary wouldn't quite address the problem @RyanReich pointed out, would it? :)

Comment: Not if you exec `zsh` itself, no, I guess not. But if you embed the resulting string in your hash bang and then exec your own script you at least know what you're getting. Still, it would make for a simpler test than for looping it.

Comment: There is also `whence -a` which would print all occurrences in `$PATH`

Answer (score 7):

For years I've used something similar to deal with the various locations of Bash on systems that I needed my scripts to run.

#### Bash/Zsh/etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Determines which OS and then reruns this script with approp. shell interp.
LIN_BASH="/bin/sh";
SOL_BASH="/packages/utilities/bin/sun5/bash";

OS_TYPE=`uname -s`;

if [ $OS_TYPE = "SunOS" ]; then
  $SOL_BASH -c "`sed -n '/\#\#\# BEGIN/,$p' $0`" $0 $*;
elif [ $OS_TYPE = "Linux" ]; then
  $LIN_BASH -c "`sed -n '/\#\#\# BEGIN/,$p' $0`" $0 $*;
else
  echo "UNKNOWN OS_TYPE, $OS_TYPE";
  exit 1;
fi
exit 0;

### BEGIN

...script goes here...
```

The above can be easily adapted for a variety of interpreters. The key piece is that this script initially runs as Bourne shell. It then recursively calls itself a second time, but parses everything out above the comment `### BEGIN` using `sed`.

#### Perl

Here's a similar trick for Perl:

```
#!/bin/sh

LIN_PERL="/usr/bin/perl";
SOL_PERL="/packages/perl/bin/perl";

OS_TYPE=`uname -s`;

if [ $OS_TYPE = "SunOS" ]; then
  eval 'exec $SOL_PERL -x -S $0 ${1+"$@"}';
elif [ $OS_TYPE = "Linux" ]; then
  eval 'exec $LIN_PERL -x -S $0 ${1+"$@"}';
else
  echo "$OS_TYPE: UNSUPORRTED OS/PLATFORM";
  exit 0;
fi
exit 0;

#!perl

...perl script goes here...
```

This method makes use of Perl's ability when given an file to run will parse said file skipping all the lines that are before the line `#! perl`.

Comment: A number of issues there: missing quotes, use of `$*` instead of `"$@"`, useless use of eval, exit status not reported (you didn't use `exec` for the first one), missing `-`/`--`, error messages not on stderr, 0 exit status for error conditions, using /bin/sh for LIN_BASH, useless semicolon (cosmetic), using all uppercase for non-env variables. `uname -s` is like `uname` (uname is for Unix name). You forgot to mention that the _skipping_ is triggered by the `-x` option to `perl`.

Answer (score 4):

#### NOTE: @jw013 makes the following *unsupported* objection in the comments below:

> The downvote is because self-modifying code is generally considered
>   bad practice. Back in the old days of tiny assembly programs it was a
>   clever way to reduce conditional branches and improve performance, but
>   nowadays the security risks outweigh the advantages. Your approach
>   would not work if the user who ran the script did not have write
>   privileges on the script.

I answered his security objections by pointing out that *any* special permissions are *only required once* per *install/update* action in order to *install/update* the *self-installing* script - which I would personally call pretty secure. I also pointed him to a [`man sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_16) reference to achieving similar goals by similar means. I did not, at the time, bother to point out that whatever security flaws or otherwise *generally unadvised practices* that may or may not be represented in my answer, they were more likely rooted in the question itself than they were in my answer to it:

> How can I set up the shebang so that running the script as
>   /path/to/script.sh always uses the Zsh available in PATH?

Not satisfied, @jw013 continued to object by furthering his *as yet unsupported* argument with at least a couple of erroneous statements:

> You use a single file, not two files. The *[`man sh` referenced]*
>   package has one file modify another file. You have a file modifying
>   itself. There is a distinct difference between these two cases. A file
>   that takes input and produces output is fine. An executable file that
>   changes itself as it runs is generally a bad idea. The example you
>   pointed to does not do that.

In the first place:

#### THE ONLY *EXECUTABLE* CODE IN ANY *EXECUTABLE* SHELL SCRIPT IS the `#!` ITSELF

*(though even `#!` is [officially unspecified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html))*

```
{   cat >|./file 
    chmod +x ./file 
    ./file
} <<-\FILE
    #!/usr/bin/sh
    {   ${l=lsof -p} $$
        echo "$l \$$" | sh
    } | grep \
        "COMMAND\|^..*sh\| [0-9]*[wru] "
#END
FILE

##OUTPUT

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
file    8900 mikeserv  txt    REG   0,33   774976  2148676 /usr/bin/bash
file    8900 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30           2148676 /usr/bin/bash (path dev=0,33)
file    8900 mikeserv    0r   REG   0,35      108 15496912 /tmp/zshUTTARQ (deleted)
file    8900 mikeserv    1u   CHR  136,2      0t0        5 /dev/pts/2
file    8900 mikeserv    2u   CHR  136,2      0t0        5 /dev/pts/2
file    8900 mikeserv  255r   REG   0,33      108  2134129 /home/mikeserv/file
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
sh      8906 mikeserv  txt    REG   0,33   774976  2148676 /usr/bin/bash
sh      8906 mikeserv  mem    REG   0,30           2148676 /usr/bin/bash (path dev=0,33)
sh      8906 mikeserv    0r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 15500515 pipe
sh      8906 mikeserv    1w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 15500514 pipe
sh      8906 mikeserv    2u   CHR  136,2      0t0        5 /dev/pts/2

{    sed -i \
         '1c#!/home/mikeserv/file' ./file 
     ./file 
     sh -c './file ; echo'
     grep '#!' ./file
}

##OUTPUT
zsh: too many levels of symbolic links: ./file
sh: ./file: /home/mikeserv/file: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links

#!/home/mikeserv/file
```

A shell script is just a text file - in order for it to have any effect at all it must be *read* by another executable file, its instructions then *interpreted* by that other executable file, before finally the other executable file then *executes its interpretation* of the shell script. It is ***not possible*** for the execution of a shell script file to ***involve fewer than two files.*** There is a possible exception in `zsh`'s own compiler, but with this I have little experience and it is in no way represented here.

A shell script's hashbang *must* point to its intended *interpreter* or be discarded as irrelevant.

#### THE SHELL'S [TOKEN RECOGNITION/EXECUTION](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03) BEHAVIOR IS STANDARDS-DEFINED

The shell has two basic modes of parsing and interpreting its input: either its current input is defining a `<<here_document` or it is defining a `{ ( command |&&|| list ) ; } &` - in other words, the shell either interprets a *token* as a delimiter for a command it should execute once it has read it in or as instructions to create a file and map it to a file descriptor for another command. That's it.

When interpreting commands to execute the shell delimits tokens on a set of *reserved words.* When the shell encounters an opening token it must continue to read in a command list until the list is either delimited by a closing token such as a newline - when applicable - or the closing token like `})` for `({` before execution.

The shell distinguishes between a *simple command* and a *compound command.* The *compound command* is the set of commands that must be read in before execution, but the shell does not perform `$expansion` on any of its constituent *simple commands* until it singly executes each one.

So, in the following example, the `;semicolon` *reserved words* delimit individual *simple commands* whereas the non-escaped `\newline` character delimits between the two *compound commands:*

```
{   cat >|./file
    chmod +x ./file
    ./file
} <<-\FILE
        #!/usr/bin/sh
        echo "simple command ${sc=1}" ;\
                : > $0 ;\
                echo "simple command $((sc+2))" ;\
                sh -c "./file && echo hooray"
        sh -c "./file && echo hooray"
#END
FILE

##OUTPUT

simple command 1
simple command 3
hooray
```

That is a simplification of the guidelines. It gets much more complicated when you consider *shell-builtins, subshells, current environment* and etc, but, for my purposes here, it is enough.

And speaking of *built-ins* and *command-lists,* a `function() { declaration ; }` is merely a means of assigning a *compound command* to a *simple command.* The shell must not perform any `$expansions` on the declaration statement itself - to include `<<redirections>` - but must instead store the definition as a single, literal string and execute it as a special shell built-in when called upon.

So a shell function declared in an executable shell script is stored in the interpreting shell's memory in its literal string form - unexpanded to include appended here-documents as input - and executed independently of its source file every time it is called as a shell built-in for as long as the shell's current environment lasts.

#### A [`<<HERE-DOCUMENT`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) IS AN INLINE FILE

> The redirection operators `<<` and `<<-` both allow redirection of
>   lines contained in a shell input file, known as a *here-document,* to
>   the input of a command.
>
> The *here-document* shall be treated as a single word that begins after
>   the next `\newline` and continues until there is a line containing only
>   the *delimiter* and a `\newline`, with no `[:blank:]`s in between. Then the
>   next *here-document* starts, if there is one. The format is as follows:

```
[n]<<word
    here-document 
delimiter
```

> ...where the optional `n` represents the file descriptor number. If the number is omitted, the *here-document* refers
>   to *standard input* (file descriptor 0).

```
for shell in dash zsh bash sh ; do sudo $shell -c '
        {   readlink /proc/self/fd/3
            cat <&3
        } 3<<-FILE
            $0

        FILE
' ; done

#OUTPUT

pipe:[16582351]
dash

/tmp/zshqs0lKX (deleted)
zsh

/tmp/sh-thd-955082504 (deleted)
bash

/tmp/sh-thd-955082612 (deleted)
sh
```

You see? For every shell above the shell creates a file and maps it to a file descriptor. In `zsh, (ba)sh` the shell creates a regular file in `/tmp`, dumps output, maps it to a descriptor, then deletes the `/tmp` file so the kernel's copy of the descriptor is all that remains. `dash` avoids all of that nonsense and simply drops its output processing into an anonymous `|pipe` file aimed at the redirect `<<` target.

This makes `dash`'s:

```
cmd <<HEREDOC
    $(cmd)
HEREDOC
```

functionally equivalent to `bash`'s:

```
cmd <(cmd)
```

while `dash`'s implementation is at least POSIXly portable.

#### WHICH MAKES *SEVERAL* FILES

So in the answer below when I do:

```
{    cat >|./file
     chmod +x ./file
     ./file
} <<\FILE
#!/usr/bin/sh
_fn() { printf '#!' ; command -v zsh ; cat 
} <<SCRIPT >$0
    [SCRIPT BODY]
SCRIPT    

_fn ; exec $0
FILE
```

The following happens:

1. I first `cat` the contents of whatever file the shell created for `FILE` into `./file`, make it executable, then execute it.
2. The kernel interprets the `#!` and calls `/usr/bin/sh` with a `<read` *file descriptor* assigned to `./file`.
3. `sh` maps a string into memory consisting of the *compound command* beginning at `_fn()` and ending at `SCRIPT`.
4. When `_fn` is called, `sh` must first interpret then map to a descriptor the file defined in `<<SCRIPT...SCRIPT` *before* invoking `_fn` as a special built-in utility because `SCRIPT` is `_fn`'s `<input.`
5. The strings output by `printf` and `command` are written out to `_fn`'s *standard-out* `>&1` - which is redirected to the current shell's `ARGV0` - or `$0`.
6. `cat` concatenates its `<&0` *standard-input* file-descriptor - `SCRIPT` - over the `>` truncated current shell's `ARGV0` argument, or `$0`.
7. Completing its already read-in current *compound command*, `sh exec`s the executable - and newly rewritten - `$0` argument.

From the time `./file` is called until its contained instructions specify that it should be `exec`d again, `sh` reads it in a single *compound command* at a time as it executes them, while `./file` itself *does nothing at all* except happily accept its new contents. The files that are actually at work are `/usr/bin/sh, /usr/bin/cat, /tmp/sh-something-or-another.`

#### THANKS, AFTER ALL

So when @jw013 specifies that:

> A file that takes input and produces output is fine...

...amidst his erroneous criticism of this answer, he is actually unwittingly condoning the only method used here, which basically works out to just:

```
cat <new_file >old_file
```

#### ANSWER

All the answers here are good, but none of them are fully correct. Everyone seems to claim you cannot dynamically and permanently path your `#!bang`. Here's a demonstration of setting up a path independent shebang:

#### DEMO

```
{   cat >|./file
    chmod +x ./file
    ./file
} <<\FILE 
#!/usr/bin/sh
_rewrite_me() { printf '#!' ; command -v zsh
        ${out+cat} ; ${out+:} . /dev/fd/0 >&2
} <<\SCRIPT >|${out-/dev/null}
        printf "
        \$0    :\t$0
        lines :\t$((c=$(wc -l <$0)))
        !bang :\t$(sed 1q "$0")
        shell :\t"$(printf `ps -o args= -p $$`)\\n\\n
        sed -n "1,2{=;p};$((c-1)),\${=;p}" "$0" |
                sed -e 'N;s/\n/ >\t/' -e 4a\\...
SCRIPT
_rewrite_me ; out=$0 _rewrite_me ; exec $0
FILE
```

#### OUTPUT

```
        $0    : ./file
        lines : 13
        !bang : #!/usr/bin/sh
        shell : /usr/bin/sh

1 >     #!/usr/bin/sh
2 >     _rewrite_me() { printf '#!' ; command -v zsh
...
12 >    SCRIPT
13 >    _rewrite_me ; out=$0 _rewrite_me ; exec $0

        $0    : /home/mikeserv/file
        lines : 8
        !bang : #!/usr/bin/zsh
        shell : /usr/bin/zsh

1 >     #!/usr/bin/zsh
2 >             printf "
...
7 >             sed -n "1,2{=;p};$((c-1)),\${=;p}" "$0" |
8 >                     sed -e 'N;s/\n/ >\t/' -e 4a\\...
```

You see? We just make the script overwrite itself. And it only ever happens once after a `git` sync. From that point on it's got the right path in the #!bang line.

Now almost all of that up there is just fluff. To do this safely you need:

1. A function defined at the top and called at the bottom that does the writing. This way we store everything we need in memory and ensure the entire file is read in before we begin writing over it.
2. Some way of determining what the path should be. `command -v` is pretty good for that.
3. Heredocs really help because they're actual files. They'll store your script in the meantime. You can use strings as well but...
4. You have to make sure that the shell reads in the command that overwrites your script in the same command list as the one that execs it.

Look:

```
{   cat >|./file
    chmod +x ./file
    ./file
} <<\FILE 
#!/usr/bin/sh
_rewrite_me() { printf '#!' ; command -v zsh
        ${out+cat} ; ${out+:} . /dev/fd/0 >&2
} <<\SCRIPT >|${out-/dev/null}
        printf "
        \$0    :\t$0
        lines :\t$((c=$(wc -l <$0)))
        !bang :\t$(sed 1q "$0")
        shell :\t"$(printf `ps -o args= -p $$`)\\n\\n
        sed -n "1,2{=;p};$((c-1)),\${=;p}" "$0" |
                sed -e 'N;s/\n/ >\t/' -e 4a\\...
SCRIPT
_rewrite_me ; out=$0 _rewrite_me
exec $0
FILE
```

Notice that I only moved the `exec` command down one line. Now:

```
#OUTPUT
        $0    : ./file
        lines : 14
        !bang : #!/usr/bin/sh
        shell : /usr/bin/sh

1 >     #!/usr/bin/sh
2 >     _rewrite_me() { printf '#!' ; command -v zsh
...
13 >    _rewrite_me ; out=$0 _rewrite_me
14 >    exec $0
```

I don't get the second half of the output because the script can't read in the next command. Still, because the only command missing was the last:

```
cat ./file

#!/usr/bin/zsh
        printf "
        \$0    :\t$0
        lines :\t$((c=$(wc -l <$0)))
        !bang :\t$(sed 1q "$0")
        shell :\t"$(printf `ps -o args= -p $$`)\\n\\n
        sed -n "1,2{=;p};$((c-1)),\${=;p}" "$0" |
                sed -e 'N;s/\n/ >\t/' -e 4a\\...
```

The script came through as it should have - mostly because it was all in the heredoc - but if you don't plan it right you can truncate your filestream, which is what happened to me above.

Comment: The downvote is because self-modifying code is generally considered bad practice. Back in the old days of tiny assembly programs it was a clever way to reduce conditional branches and improve performance, but nowadays the security risks outweigh the advantages. Your approach would not work if the user who ran the script did not have write privileges on the script.

Comment: @jw013 Obviously my approach to *install or update an executable script* would not work if the person attempting to *install or update the script* did not have permissions to *install or update the script.* in fact, that is specifically what makes this answer better than every other answer here - it can provide an accurate #!bang line as necessary and only needs any special permissions to do so at the first invocation - during *installation.* And, again, i will not simply take your word for it that *self modifying code is bad practice* - please see `man command` for a contradictory opinion.

Comment: *please see `man command` for a contradictory opinion* - not finding one. Can you direct me to the specific section / paragraph you were talking about?

Comment: @jw013 - my mistake, it's in `man sh` - search for *'command -v'.* I knew it was in one of the `man` pages i was looking at the other day.

Comment: I assume [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_16) is the `command -v` example you were talking about from `man sh`. That is a normal-looking installer script, and not a *self-modifying* one. Even self-contained installers only contain pre-modification input, and output their modifications somewhere else. They don't rewrite themselves the way you are recommending.

Comment: @jw013 - that is a *module* of a *package* that  *modifies the package's source* - so yes, it is *self-modifying.* It uses *two files* to do so - in much the  same way i do above. Why are you so contradictory? If you dont understand a thing, simply say so - dont offer expert advice if you have none to give. Please.

Comment: You use a single file, not two files. The package has one file modify another file. You have a file modifying itself. There is a distinct difference between these two cases. A file that takes input and produces output is fine. An executable file that changes itself as it runs is generally a bad idea. The example you pointed to does not do that.

Comment: @jw013 - `cat <./file >./file` cant give you anything but the original file. But `cat <./file2 >./file` is what i do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to have a self modifying script that fix its shebang. This code should be prepended to your actual script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# unpatched

PATH=`PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH getconf PATH`
if [ "`awk 'NR==2 {print $2;exit;}' $0`" = unpatched ]; then
  [ -z "`PATH=\`getconf PATH\`:/usr/local/bin:/some/long/path/to/the/right:$PATH command -v zsh`" ] && { echo "zsh not found"; exit 1; }
  cp -- "$0" "$0.org" || exit 1
  mv -- "$0" "$0.old" || exit 1
  (
    echo "#!`PATH=\`getconf PATH\`:$PATH command -v zsh`" 
    sed -n '/^##/,$p' $0.old
  ) > $0 || exit
  chmod +x $0
  rm $0.old
  sync
  exit
fi
## Original script starts here
```

Some comments:

- It should be run once by someone who has the rights to create and delete files in the directory where the script is located.
- It only uses legacy bourne shell syntax as, despite popular belief, `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to be a POSIX shell, even en POSIX compliant OSes.
- It set the PATH to a POSIX compliant one followed by a list of possible zsh locations to avoid picking a "phony" zsh.
- If for some reason, a self modifying script is unwelcomed, it would be trivial to distribute two scripts instead of one, the first one being the one you want to patch and the second one, the one I suggested slightly modified to process the former.

Comment: The `/bin/sh` point is a good one - but in that case do you need a premodified `#!` at all? And isn't `awk` just as likely to be *phony* as `zsh` is?

Comment: @mikeserv Answer updated to call the POSIX awk. The premodified shebang is there to prevent the script to be interpreted by a non bourne compatible shell should it be your login shell.

Comment: Makes sense. I upvoted it because it works, it sticks to the book and it demonstrates sound understanding of possible shell environment/file handling - especially the backup files you use, which is all GNU's `sed -i` does anyway. I personally think the `$PATH` problem noted in the comments on another answer and which you address as safely as i can figure here in a few lines is better handled by simply and explicitly defining dependencies and/or rigorous and explicit testing - for instance, now `getconf` might be *phony,* but the chances are near nil, same as they were for `zsh` and `awk.`

Comment: @mikeserv, script modified to reduce the risk to call a bogus getconf.

Comment: `$(getconf PATH)` is not Bourne. `cp $0 $0.old` is zsh syntax. The Bourne equivalent would be `cp "$0" "$0.old"` though you'd want `cp -- "$0" "$0.old"`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Many thanks, script corrected according to your advices.