# Functions defined in .zshrc not found when running script

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have a function in `.zshrc` that mostly updates the `PATH`:

```
my_function()
{
        PATH=...
}
```

and some scripts that depend on it, e.g. `my_script.sh` starts with the following lines:

```
my_function
# do stuff ...
```

I then have the following in `crontab`:

```
00 02 * * * /path/to/my/zsh /path/to/my_script.sh
```

but I have noticed that, even when I run `my_script.sh` as `./my_script.sh` manually (i.e. from my interactive(?) Zsh shell), I get the error:

```
Command not found: my_function
```

even though I can perfectly invoke `my_function` from the terminal.

Why? I would like a solution that does **not** require me to add a shebang to my script (for more on this see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126812/path-independent-shebangs))

I [found](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) the following diagram. I imagine that in my case, cron launches a non-interactive, non-login shell, which is why none of the init files are run. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: Is your `.sh` script run with a zsh interpreter? Even if you put your functions in the right place for a zsh interpreter to find them, they won't get sourced if you are using a bash interpreter to run your script.

Comment: That diagram applies to bash, not to zsh.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. Besides references to `.zshenv`, do you know what else is potentially missing?

Comment: Functions defined in a script that is executed (not sourced) will not be available after that script completes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put your functions in `.zshenv`.

`.zshenv` is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the `-f` option is set. It should contain commands to set the command search path, plus other important environment variables. `.zshenv` should not contain commands that produce output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.

`.zshrc` is sourced in interactive shells. It should contain commands to set up aliases, functions, options, key bindings, etc.

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: Thanks -- Is there an equivalent mechanism for Bash?

Comment: Dont think so, what you can do is create a ".shared_functions" file and add "source /path/to/.shared_functions" to the script.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep my shell function definitions separate from my .zshrc.

So, for what it's worth, I've had luck accessing shell functions from emacs by simply including the directory which contains my zsh functions ($HOME/.zsh) in my $PATH.

As always, YMMV.