# Run .zshrc when passing command via -c

Tags: shell, zsh, rc

I have a script that runs a command via `zsh -c`. However, when `zsh` runs, it doesn't appear to load `~/.zshrc`.

I understand [a login shell flag exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126956/functions-defined-in-zshrc-not-found-when-running-script), but even `zsh -lc <command>` doesn't seem to work.

How can I get functions, aliases, and variables defined in my *~/.zshrc* to populate when running it with `zsh -c`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`zsh` do not read `.zshrc` in non-interactive shell, but `zsh` allow you to [invoke an interactive shell to run a script](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Invocation.html#Invocation):

```
$ zsh -ic 'type f'
f is a shell function
```

or you can always source `.zshrc` manually:

```
$ zsh -c '. ~/.zshrc; type f'
f is a shell function
```

Answer (score 0):

While `zsh` doesn't load `.zshrc` in non-interactive shells, as cuonglm said, it [*does* load `.zshenv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html). So if you're doing setup that doesn't require a tty, such as configuring your `$PATH`, that can (and probably should) be done in `.zshenv`.

From the [zsh docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html):

> `.zshenv` is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the -f option is set. It should contain commands to set the command search path, plus other important environment variables. `.zshenv` should not contain commands that produce output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.